# Google translate widget mobile overflow

Tags: jquery, css, google-translate

I'm having a bit of a problem with google's translate plugin on my site. It appears fine in desktop mode but as I move down to mobile the width of the dropdown exceeds the browser width. 
[image]

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

best regards

Comment: Apply the dropdown and it s parent section is to width:100%

Comment: @iyyappan that doesn't work because the widget is generated after the css files are loaded. Have to inject it with the css onClick with jQuery

Comment: yes sure.Use !important with injected CSS. else use setTimeout function with Width:100%

Answer (score 3):

As you can't add css to elements that don't exist you have to add it after you click on the translate dropdown CTA. This jquery works for me.

```
$('body').click('#google_translate_element', function () {
    if (($goog = $('.goog-te-menu-frame').contents().find('body')).length) {
        var stylesHtml = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/google-translate.css">';
        $goog.prepend(stylesHtml);
    }
});
```

With this css.

```
.goog-te-menu2 {
    width: 300px!important;
    height: 300px!important;
    overflow: auto!important;
}
.goog-te-menu2 table,
.goog-te-menu2 table tbody,
.goog-te-menu2 table tbody tr {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 100%!important;
}
.goog-te-menu2 table tbody tr td {
    width: 100%!important;
    display: block!important;
}
.goog-te-menu2 table tbody tr td .goog-te-menu2-colpad {
    visibility: none!important;
}
```